# Can I post about Filezilla corrupting my database here?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I'm having issues with Filezilla somehow deleting all my data in an SQLite database. Can I ask that question here or does that belong elsewhere?

Comment: Probably belongs on [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: Maybe post nowhere. FTP has a long history of downloading binary files as text, thus corrupting the original file. That should be enough for you to find a solution.

Comment: I haven't found a single solution that isn't an ambiguous "don't use that". Not to mention I can't confirm with certainty that solely Filezilla is the culprit. I do understand that's a common issue, but solutions and explanations are seldom offered as most have alternatives, I do not in my environment.

Answer (score 3):

If [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is about the *free* FileTranportProtocol solution and your actual question is about a certain usage scenario of those tools leading to an issue then [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) is probably the best site to start with.

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users if you have a question about computer software

I assume you already ruled out your question is about *programming and software development* or *an issue specific to corporate IT support and networks* as that would be a dis-qualifier for being on-topic on Super User.

There are some questions on Super User about [FileZilla and file corruption](https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bfilezilla%5D+corrupt) but if you want to have success with your question be sure to include context (OS, Filesystem, permissions, versions) and a reproducible scenario, preferable without having to install a complete toolstack.

Comment: Could you rephrase that last part, please? The statement kind of runs and seems confusing.

Comment: Nevermind, I get what you're saying now haha. So I haven't rule that out as my Python or SQL could be a potential culprit too. How would you recommend being able to lay out ALL information on the issue without being flagged off-topic in 1 of the 2 sites? If I include my Python on SuperUser, will I be scrutinized and vice versa if I include how I'm transferring files on StackOverflow will it be marked off-topic?

Comment: Don't use FileZilla and see if the problem persists

Comment: That's unfortunately not a viable option in my circumstance, but thank you.

Comment: So do you believe including my code at SuperUser would be permittable or be flagged?

Comment: I'm not sure. I asked an SU mod to take a look at my answer. Let's wait for his feedback.